# saving hexadecimal value in .dat file

Tags: c, ubuntu

In a tutorial the writer saves 48 bytes of padding followed by the address 0x601040 in a file called data1.dat.The writer then shows this output:

```
$ hexdump data1.dat -vC
00000000  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000010  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000020  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000030  40 10 60 00 00 00 00 00                           |@.`.....|
00000038
```

I created a file called data1.dat on my 64 bit Ubuntu containing:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4010600000000000
```

but when I type hexdump data1.dat -vC I get:

```
test@test-VirtualBox:~$ hexdump data1.dat -vC
00000000  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000010  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000020  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41  |AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA|
00000030  34 30 31 30 36 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |4010600000000000|
00000040  0a                                                |.|
00000041
test@test-VirtualBox:~$
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong, is not showing the source code of the writer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Do you know the difference between binary and text data?

Comment: @Eugene Sh if you have time could you explain what i should do to fix this problem or where i can find information about this.

Comment: You are creating file containing **characters** '4', '0' and so on, while their hexadecimal ascii representation is `34`, `30` and so on respectively. And it is what you see in the dump.